# Approximating inverse trigonometric functions

Tags: algorithm, math, trigonometry

I have to implement asin, acos and atan in environment where I have only following math tools:

- sine
- cosine
- elementary fixed point arithmetic (floating point numbers are not available)

I also already have reasonably good square root function.

**Can I use those to implement reasonably efficient inverse trigonometric functions?**

I don't need too big precision (the floating point numbers have very limited precision anyways), basic approximation will do.

I'm already half decided to go with table lookup, but I would like to know if there is some neater option (that doesn't need several hundred lines of code just to implement basic math).

EDIT:

**To clear things up**: I need to run the function hundreds of times per frame at 35 frames per second.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do Trigonometric functions work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/345085/how-do-trigonometric-functions-work)

Comment: The proposed duplicate is more about how trigonometric functions work (just like it's title).  This is about the inverse trigonometric functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you need a large precision for `arcsin(x)` function? If no you may calculate `arcsin` in N nodes, and keep values in memory. I suggest using line aproximation. if `x = A*x_(N) + (1-A)*x_(N+1)` then  `x = A*arcsin(x_(N)) + (1-A)*arcsin(x_(N+1))` where `arcsin(x_(N))`  is known.

Comment: Yeah, that's the table lookup I was talking about in OP.  don't see a reason why I would calculated that at runtime, I would simoly bake the values into the program, so the actual asin calculation would just be an interpolation between two values.

Answer (score 9):

In a fixed-point environment (S15.16) I successfully used the CORDIC algorithm (see Wikipedia for a general description) to compute atan2(y,x), then derived asin() and acos() from that using well-known functional identities that involve the square root:

```
asin(x) = atan2 (x, sqrt ((1.0 + x) * (1.0 - x)))
acos(x) = atan2 (sqrt ((1.0 + x) * (1.0 - x)), x)
```

It turns out that finding a useful description of the CORDIC iteration for atan2() on the double is harder than I thought. The following website appears to contain a sufficiently detailed description, and also discusses two alternative approaches, polynomial approximation and lookup tables:

http://ch.mathworks.com/examples/matlab-fixed-point-designer/615-calculate-fixed-point-arctangent

Comment: From wikipedia, CORDIC doesn't even use the trig functions (neat!); I imagine what you did was a search; given sin(), cos() it seems Newton-Raphson or some such would be better?  (Require fewer iterations, although the cost of the iterations would be different.)

Comment: The reason I suggested looking into CORDIC is because it only requires fixed-point arithmetic. The most common use of CORDIC is probably for implementing sin / cos, that is how I first learned about it (in 1987). But quite a few other functions can be computed with CORDIC as well, such as atan2. Since I do not have any code lying around for computing atan2 with CORDIC I tried to find a website with enough detail that someone could base an implementation on it. The link I posted above was the best page I could find via a search engine in the space of a few minutes.

Answer (score 2):

you might want to use approximation: use an [infinite series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_trigonometric_functions#Infinite_series) until the solution is close enough for you.

for example: 

`arcsin(z) = Sigma((2n!)/((2^2n)*(n!)^2)*((z^(2n+1))/(2n+1)))` where n in [0,infinity)

Answer (score 2):

[image: Expression as definite integrals]

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_trigonometric_functions#Expression_as_definite_integrals

You could do that integration numerically with your square root function, approximating with an infinite series:

[image: Infinite series]

Answer (score 2):

It should be easy to addapt the following code to fixed point. It employs a [rational approximation](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/6375931) to calculate the arctangent normalized to the [0 1) interval (you can multiply it by Pi/2 to get the real arctangent). Then, you can use [well known identities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7378187/approximating-inverse-trigonometric-functions/7380529#7380529) to get the arcsin/arccos from the arctangent.

```
normalized_atan(x) ~ (b x + x^2) / (1 + 2 b x + x^2)
 
where b = 0.596227
```

The maximum error is 0.1620º

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <math.h>

// Approximates atan(x) normalized to the [-1,1] range
// with a maximum error of 0.1620 degrees.

float norm_atan( float x )
{
    static const uint32_t sign_mask = 0x80000000;
    static const float b = 0.596227f;

    // Extract the sign bit
    uint32_t ux_s  = sign_mask & (uint32_t &)x;

    // Calculate the arctangent in the first quadrant
    float bx_a = ::fabs( b * x );
    float num = bx_a + x * x;
    float atan_1q = num / ( 1.f + bx_a + num );

    // Restore the sign bit
    uint32_t atan_2q = ux_s | (uint32_t &)atan_1q;
    return (float &)atan_2q;
}

// Approximates atan2(y, x) normalized to the [0,4) range
// with a maximum error of 0.1620 degrees

float norm_atan2( float y, float x )
{
    static const uint32_t sign_mask = 0x80000000;
    static const float b = 0.596227f;

    // Extract the sign bits
    uint32_t ux_s  = sign_mask & (uint32_t &)x;
    uint32_t uy_s  = sign_mask & (uint32_t &)y;

    // Determine the quadrant offset
    float q = (float)( ( ~ux_s & uy_s ) >> 29 | ux_s >> 30 ); 

    // Calculate the arctangent in the first quadrant
    float bxy_a = ::fabs( b * x * y );
    float num = bxy_a + y * y;
    float atan_1q =  num / ( x * x + bxy_a + num );

    // Translate it to the proper quadrant
    uint32_t uatan_2q = (ux_s ^ uy_s) | (uint32_t &)atan_1q;
    return q + (float &)uatan_2q;
}
```

In case you need more precision, there is a 3rd order rational function:

```
normalized_atan(x) ~ ( c x + x^2 + x^3) / ( 1 + (c + 1) x + (c + 1) x^2 + x^3)
 
where c = (1 + sqrt(17)) / 8
```

which has a maximum approximation error of 0.00811º

Answer (score 2):

Submitting here my answer from this [other similar question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3380628/fast-arc-cos-algorithm/26030435#26030435)

nVidia has some great resources I've used for my own uses, few examples: [acos](http://http.developer.nvidia.com/Cg/acos.html) [asin](http://http.developer.nvidia.com/Cg/asin.html) [atan2](http://http.developer.nvidia.com/Cg/atan2.html) etc etc...

These algorithms produce precise enough results. Here's a straight up Python example with their code copy pasted in:

```
import math
def nVidia_acos(x):
    negate = float(x<0)
    x=abs(x)
    ret = -0.0187293
    ret = ret * x
    ret = ret + 0.0742610
    ret = ret * x
    ret = ret - 0.2121144
    ret = ret * x
    ret = ret + 1.5707288
    ret = ret * math.sqrt(1.0-x)
    ret = ret - 2 * negate * ret
    return negate * 3.14159265358979 + ret
```

And here are the results for comparison:

```
nVidia_acos(0.5)  result: 1.0471513828611643
math.acos(0.5)    result: 1.0471975511965976
```

That's pretty close! Multiply by 57.29577951 to get results in degrees, which is also from their "degrees" formula.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe some kind of intelligent brute force like newton rapson.

So for solving asin() you go with steepest descent on sin()

Comment: and you can choose the starting point from a small lookup-table to speed up the calculation.

Answer (score 0):

Use a polynomial approximation. Least-squares fit is easiest (Microsoft Excel has it) and Chebyshev approximation is more accurate.

This question has been covered before: [How do Trigonometric functions work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/345085/how-do-trigonometric-functions-work)

Answer (score -1):

Only continous  functions are approximable by polynomials. And arcsin(x) is discontinous in point x=1.same arccos(x).But a range reduction to interval 1,sqrt(1/2) in that case avoid this situation. We have arcsin(x)=pi/2- arccos(x),arccos(x)=pi/2-arcsin(x).you can use matlab for minimax approximation.Aproximate only in range [0,sqrt(1/2)](if angle for that arcsin is request is bigger that sqrt(1/2) find cos(x).arctangent function only for x<1.arctan(x)=pi/2-arctan(1/x).