# Fast & accurate atan/arctan approximation algorithm

Tags: c, algorithm, math, trigonometry

Any fast & accurate atan/arctan approximation function/algorithm out there? Input: x = (0, 1] (minimum x requirement). Output: in radians

```
double FastArcTan(double x)
{
    return M_PI_4*x - x*(fabs(x) - 1)*(0.2447 + 0.0663*fabs(x));
}
```

I've found this function above online but it gave a max error of 1.6 radians which is too big.

Comment: You have typed the wrong Google url...

Comment: Not sure where that formula came from... have you looked at just using first order approximation (as pointed out in http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/128514/solving-the-arctan-of-an-angle-radians-by-hand) ... something like  x - (1.0/3) * (x ** 3) + (1.0/5) * (x ** 5) won't be perfect (and the error grows the closer you get to 1) but I'm pretty sure it will be < 1.6 radians

Comment: If you are willing to precompute a few values with a slow, accurate arctan algorithm, then you can use piecewise polynomial interpolation. The benefit of piecewise polynomial interpolation is that you can get almost any arbitrary amount of precision; it only depends on how many precomputed values you are willing to have. You can algebraically determine the number of values you need to store to get your desired precision.

Comment: OP's formula comes from *Efficient Approximations for the Arctangent Function*. The formula has a maximum absolute error of 0.0015 rad (0.086º).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

OP reported a max error of 1.6 radians (92 degrees) which is inconsistent with testing OP's code below, max error input `x`: 0 to 1 range of about 0.0015 radians.  I suspect a mis-code or testing outside the range of 0...1.  Did OP means 1.6 milli-radians?

---

Perhaps a more accurate `a*x^5 + b*x^3 + c*x` will still be fast enough for OP.  It is about 4x more accurate on my machine on average and 2x better worst case.  It uses an optimal 3-term polynomial as suggested by [@Foon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42537957/fast-accurate-atan-arctan-approximation-algorithm/42542593#comment72213915_42537957) and [@Matthew Pope](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5563569/matthew-pope)

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#ifndef M_PI_4
#define M_PI_4 (3.1415926535897932384626433832795/4.0)
#endif

double FastArcTan(double x) {
  return M_PI_4*x - x*(fabs(x) - 1)*(0.2447 + 0.0663*fabs(x));
}

#define A 0.0776509570923569
#define B -0.287434475393028
#define C (M_PI_4 - A - B)
#define FMT "% 16.8f"

double Fast2ArcTan(double x) {
  double xx = x * x;
  return ((A*xx + B)*xx + C)*x;
}

int main() {
  double mxe1 = 0, mxe2 = 0;
  double err1 = 0, err2 = 0;
  int n = 100;
  for (int i=-n;i<=n; i++) {
    double x = 1.0*i/n;
    double y = atan(x);
    double y_fast1 = FastArcTan(x);
    double y_fast2 = Fast2ArcTan(x);
    printf("%3d x:% .3f y:" FMT "y1:" FMT "y2:" FMT "\n", i, x, y, y_fast1, y_fast2);
    if (fabs(y_fast1 - y) > mxe1 ) mxe1  = fabs(y_fast1 - y);
    if (fabs(y_fast2 - y) > mxe2 ) mxe2  = fabs(y_fast2 - y);
    err1 += (y_fast1 - y)*(y_fast1 - y);
    err2 += (y_fast2 - y)*(y_fast2 - y);
  }
  printf("max error1: " FMT "sum sq1:" FMT "\n", mxe1, err1);
  printf("max error2: " FMT "sum sq2:" FMT "\n", mxe2, err2);
}
```

Output

```
 ...
 96 x: 0.960 y:      0.76499283y1:      0.76582280y2:      0.76438526
 97 x: 0.970 y:      0.77017091y1:      0.77082844y2:      0.76967407
 98 x: 0.980 y:      0.77529750y1:      0.77575981y2:      0.77493733
 99 x: 0.990 y:      0.78037308y1:      0.78061652y2:      0.78017777
100 x: 1.000 y:      0.78539816y1:      0.78539816y2:      0.78539816
max error1:       0.00150847sum sq1:      0.00023062
max error2:       0.00084283sum sq2:      0.00004826
```

---

Unclear why OP's code uses `fabs()` given "Input: x = (0, 1]".

---

[**Update 2024**]

For low precision functions such as `double FastArcTan(double x)`, we can optimize the error at least 3 ways: error, relative error and unit in the last place error.  With `float x` values in the range [0 ... 1.0], we can test every `float` and report the worst case.

**Error** is simply `fast_f(x) - reference(x)`.

**Relative error** is `(fast_f(x) - reference(x))/reference(x)` with special consideration when `reference(x)` is 0 or a sub-normal number - using `(fast_f(x) - reference(x))/FLT_MIN` in those cases.

**Unit in the last place (ULP) error** is the the number of `float` away from the best answer.  [Example](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/288625/29485).  It is approximately `(fast_f(x) - reference(x))/round_down_to_a_power_of_2(reference(x))`.

OP, with "gave a max error of 1.6 radians" wants to optimize the **error**.

In my experience, usually it is the **relative error** or **ULP error** that is desired to minimize.

This update reviews code to see if we can do better with some restrictions:

- Only interested in `float` values in the primary range [0.0 ... 1.0].
- No wider than `float` math coded.
- Although `fmaf()` is useful to extend precision, it is not used here given that simple/fast trig functions are often needed on systems without a hardware fuse-multiply-add and good software ones are slow.
- The end points `f(0.0)` and `f(1.0)` report the best result (e.g. `0.0`, `M_PI/4`).  If we tolerate more error in the ends, we can *somewhat* reduce overall errors.  IMO, it is often desirable that the end-points have minimal error.

Test results:

```
                       :     radians,           %,         ULP
atanf (C library)      : 0.000000051, 0.000008442,       0.852
FastArcTan -OP         : 0.001508884, 5.882352941,  490209.000
Fast2ArcTan-This answer: 0.000843262, 0.961538462,   80838.000
atan_abs3-optimize err : 0.000704068, 1.041666667,   87799.000
atan_rel3-optimize rel : 0.001353447, 0.370370370,   31179.000
atan_ulp3-optimize UDP : 0.001581718, 0.315457413,   26536.822
atan_ulp9-optimize UDP : 0.000000095, 0.000012706,       1.592
atan_jw    -jw         : 0.000157066, 0.019998672,    2635.133
atan_jw_alt-optimize   : 0.000006579, 0.001461326,     111.129
```

`atan_abs3()` achieves a better result than `Fast2ArcTan()` for OP's goals.

I recommend `atan_ulp3()` for those wanting a few term low relative error.

---

```
float atan_abs3(float x) {
  const float a[3] = { //
      0.994766756708199f, -2.8543851807526100E-01f, 0.0760699247645105f};
  float xx = x * x;
  return ((a[2] * xx + a[1]) * xx + a[0]) * x;
}

float atan_rel3(float x) {
  const float a[3] = { //
      0.998141572179073f, -2.9774125603673200E-01f, 0.0849978472551071f};
  float xx = x * x;
  return ((a[2] * xx + a[1]) * xx + a[0]) * x;
}
float atan_ulp3(float x) {
  const float a[3] = { // 
      0.998418889819911f, -2.9993501171084700E-01f, 0.0869142852883849f};
  float xx = x * x;
  return ((a[2] * xx + a[1]) * xx + a[0]) * x;
}

float atan_ulp9(float x) {
  static const float a[9] = { {1.0f, -0.333331728467737f, 0.199940412794435f,
      -0.142123340834229f, 0.10668127080775f, -0.0755120841589429f,
      0.0431408641542157f, -0.0162911733512761f, 0.00289394245323327f}};
  float xx = x * x;
  float sum = 0.0;
  for (unsigned i = 9; i-- > 0;) {
    sum = sum * xx + a[i];
  }
  return sum * x;
}

float atan_jw(float x) {
  return 8 * x / (3 + sqrtf(25 + 80.0f / 3.0f * x * x));
}

float atan_jw_alt(float x) {
  return 8.430893743524f * x / (3.2105332277903100f + sqrtf(27.2515970979709f + 29.3591908371266f * x * x));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I realized that some of my inputs for the OP's code were >1 so that's why it was giving me max error of 1.6 radians. OP's code used fabs() because it works for input range of [-1,1], the (0,1] was just the range for my own input data.

Comment: @YingyanWang A common range reduction for `x > 1`, use something like `return M_PI_2 - FastArcTan(1/x)` and similar code for `x < 1`.  See http://stackoverflow.com/a/23097989/2410359

Comment: How did you calculate the coefficients A,B,C?

Comment: @AnhDũngLê It has been 5 years.  Hmmm., IIRC, For `A,B`, I did a best quadratic fit with Excel over a couple hundred evenly spaced data points. `C = (M_PI_4 - A - B)` to fit the curve at `x = 1.0`.

Comment: 0.07933903622614606*x^5-0.28869023238086666*x^3+0.9953579537766772*x, this is slightly better with max error 6.086E-4 in range [0, 1]. That is, if you don't mind it's value at point 1.0 is not exactly pi/4.

Comment: Or 0.07606631753154554*x^5-0.2854342007925691*x^3+0.9947660466584719*x if atan(1) should be close to pi/4, error about 7.04E-4

Comment: @ntysdd Interesting.  Now all we need is a test harness that shows average and worse case.

Answer (score 4):

I have developed the following function for my needs based on the Pade-Chebyshev approximation. The code is written under Visual Studio (x86) and works in the entire range of source data. The function is only slightly inferior in accuracy to the standard atanf function, but significantly faster than it.

```
// Fast arctangent with single precission
_declspec(naked) float _vectorcall arctg(float x)
{
  // When |x|<=1 following formula is used:
  //
  //                       a0 + a0*a1*x^2 + a0*a2*x^4 + a0*a3*x^6
  // arctg x = x * ------------------------------------------------------- = x*P(x)/Q(x)
  //                a0 + a0*(a1+b0)*x^2 + a0*(a2+b1)*x^4 + a0*(a3+b2)*x^6
  //
  // The a0 constant is reduced, but it is needed to less the error
  // and prevent overflow at large |x|.
  // P(x) and Q(x) are 3th degree polinomials of x^2.
  // When 1<|x|<62919776 (approx.) used formula is
  //
  //                                     pi/2*|x|*x^6*Q(1/x)-x^6*P(1/x)
  // arctg x = pi/2*sgn(x)-arctg(1/x) = --------------------------------
  //                                             x*x^6*Q(1/x)
  //
  // Here x^6*P(1/x) and x^6*Q(1/x) are 3th degree polinomials of x^2 too.
  // When |x|>=62919776 used formula is arctg x = pi/2*sgn(x)
  // To improve accuracy at |x|>1 the constant pi/2 is replaced by the sum (pi-3)/2 and 3/2.
  //
  static const float ct[14] =   // Constants table
  {
    6.28740248E-17f,            // a0*(a1+b0)=a0*c1
    4.86816205E-17f,            // a0*a1
    2.24874633E-18f,            // a0*(a3+b2)=a0*c3
    4.02179944E-19f,            // a0*a3
    4.25772129E-17f,            // a0
    4.25772129E-17f,            // a0
    2.50182216E-17f,            // a0*(a2+b1)=a0*c2
    1.25756219E-17f,            // a0*a2
    0.0707963258f,              // (pi-3)/2
    1.5f,                       // 3/2
    1.0f,                       // 1
    -0.0707963258f,             // -(pi-3)/2
    -1.5f,                      // -3/2
    3.95889818E15f              // Threshold of x^2 when arctg(x)=pi/2*sgn(x)
  };
  _asm
  {
    vshufps xmm1,xmm0,xmm0,0    // xmm1 = x # x : x # x
    mov edx,offset ct           // edx contains the address of constants table
    vmulps xmm2,xmm1,xmm1       // xmm2 = x^2 # x^2 : x^2 # x^2
    vmovups xmm3,[edx+16]       // xmm3 = a0*a2 # a0*c2 : a0 # a0
    vmulps xmm4,xmm2,xmm2       // xmm4 = y^2 # y^2 : y^2 # y^2
    vucomiss xmm2,[edx+40]      // Compare y=x^2 to 1
    ja arctg_big                // Jump if |x|>1
    vfmadd231ps xmm3,xmm2,[edx] // xmm3 ~ a3*y+a2 # c3*y+c2 : a1*y+1 # c1*y+1
    vmovhlps xmm1,xmm1,xmm3     // xmm1 ~ a3*y+a2 # c3*y+c2
    vfmadd231ps xmm3,xmm4,xmm1  // xmm3 ~ a3*y^3+a2*y^2+a1*y+1 # c3*y^3+c2*y^2+c1*y+1
    vmovshdup xmm2,xmm3         // xmm2 = P; xmm3 = Q
    vdivss xmm2,xmm2,xmm3       // xmm2 = P/Q
    vmulss xmm0,xmm0,xmm2       // xmm0 = x*P/Q = arctg(x)
    ret                         // Return
      arctg_big:                // When |x|>1 use formula pi/2*sgn(x)-arctg(1/x)
    vfmadd213ps xmm3,xmm2,[edx] // xmm3 ~ a2*y+a3 # c2*y+c3 : y+a1 # y+c1
    vmovmskpd eax,xmm1          // eax=3 if x<0, otherwise eax=0
    vmovhlps xmm0,xmm0,xmm3     // xmm0 ~ a2*y+a3 # c2*y+c3
    vfmadd213ps xmm3,xmm4,xmm0  // xmm3 ~ y^3+a1*y^2+a2*y+a3 # y^3+c1*y^2+c2*y+c3
    vmovss xmm0,[edx+4*eax+32]  // xmm0 = (pi-3)/2*sgn(x)
    vucomiss xmm2,[edx+52]      // Compare y=x^2 to threshold value
    jnb arctg_end               // The data is already in xmm0, if |x|>=62919776
    vmovshdup xmm4,xmm3         // xmm4 = P; xmm3 = Q
    vmulss xmm1,xmm1,xmm3       // xmm1 = x*Q
    vfmsub132ss xmm0,xmm4,xmm1  // xmm0 = (pi-3)/2*|x|*Q-P
    vdivss xmm0,xmm0,xmm1       // xmm0 = (pi-3)/2*sgn(x)-P/(x*Q)
      arctg_end:                // Add to result 3/2*sgn(x)
    vaddss xmm0,xmm0,[edx+4*eax+36] // xmm0 = pi/2*sgn(x)-P/(x*Q)
    ret                         // Return
  }
}
```

Below is similar code for the arctangent function returns the angle in degrees.

```
_declspec(naked) float _vectorcall arctgD(float x) // arctangent in degrees
{
  static const float ct[12] =       // Constants table
  {
    1.92582580E-14f,                // a0*(a1+b0)=a0*c1
    8.54345240E-13f,                // a0*a1 (in degrees)
    6.88789034E-16f,                // a0*(a3+b2)=a0*c3
    7.05811633E-15f,                // a0*a3 (in degrees)
    1.30413631E-14f,                // a0
    7.47215061E-13f,                // a0 (in degrees)
    7.66305964E-15f,                // a0*(a2+b1)=a0*c2
    2.20697728E-13f,                // a0*a2 (in degrees)
    90.0f,                          // 90
    1.0f,                           // 1
    2.25592738E14f,                 // Threshold of x^2 when arctgD(x)=90*sgn(x)
    -90.0f                          // -90
  };
  _asm
  {
    vshufps xmm1,xmm0,xmm0,0        // xmm1 = x # x : x # x
    mov edx,offset ct               // edx contains the address of constants table
    vmulps xmm2,xmm1,xmm1           // xmm2 = x^2 # x^2 : x^2 # x^2
    vmovups xmm3,[edx+16]           // xmm3 = a0*a2 # a0*c2 : a0 # a0
    vmulps xmm4,xmm2,xmm2           // xmm4 = y^2 # y^2 : y^2 # y^2
    vucomiss xmm2,[edx+36]          // Compare y=x^2 to 1
    ja arctg_big                    // Goto if |x|>1
    vfmadd231ps xmm3,xmm2,[edx]     // xmm3 ~ a3*y+a2 # c3*y+c2 : a1*y+1 # c1*y+1
    vmovhlps xmm1,xmm1,xmm3         // xmm1 ~ a3*y+a2 # c3*y+c2
    vfmadd231ps xmm3,xmm4,xmm1      // xmm3 ~ a3*y^3+a2*y^2+a1*y+1 # c3*y^3+c2*y^2+c1*y+1
    vmovshdup xmm2,xmm3             // xmm2 = P; xmm3 = Q
    vdivss xmm2,xmm2,xmm3           // xmm2 = P/Q
    vmulss xmm0,xmm0,xmm2           // xmm0 = x*P/Q = arctgD(x)
    ret                             // Return
      arctg_big:                    // When |x|>1 use formula 90*sgn(x)-arctgD(1/x)
    vfmadd213ps xmm3,xmm2,[edx]     // xmm3 ~ a2*y+a3 # c2*y+c3 : y+a1 # y+c1
    vmovmskpd eax,xmm1              // eax=3 if x<0, otherwise eax=0
    vmovhlps xmm0,xmm0,xmm3         // xmm0 ~ a2*y+a3 # c2*y+c3
    vfmadd213ps xmm3,xmm4,xmm0      // xmm3 ~ y^3+a1*y^2+a2*y+a3 # y^3+c1*y^2+c2*y+c3
    vmovss xmm0,[edx+4*eax+32]      // xmm0 = 90*sgn(x)
    vcomiss xmm2,[edx+40]           // Compare y=x^2 to threshold value
    jnb arctg_end                   // If |x|>=15019745 result already done
    vmovshdup xmm4,xmm3             // xmm4 = P; xmm3 = Q
    vmulss xmm1,xmm1,xmm3           // xmm1 = x*Q
    vdivss xmm4,xmm4,xmm1           // xmm4 = P/(x*Q)
    vsubss xmm0,xmm0,xmm4           // xmm0 = 90*sgn(x)-P/(x*Q)
      arctg_end:                    // xmm0 = arctgD(x)
    ret                             // Return
  }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! If possible, could you write the code comments in English?

Comment: "The function is only slightly inferior in accuracy to the standard atanf function, but significantly faster than it." --> over what range of `x` did you assess accuracy?

Comment: The function provides almost complete float accuracy over the entire range. The error is mainly due to rounding errors of intermediate calculation results. The approximating fractional-rational function itself has a relative error of no more than 3*10^-9, which exceeds the accuracy of the float format.

Comment: I suspect the speed up is at least partially due to this answer only copes with [0...1) whereas the standard function must deal with the entire `x` range.

Comment: The function I proposed works for any x. But for |x|>1 it works somewhat slower than for |x|<=1. Because |x|>1 requires a little more computation.

Comment: @njuffa When 4.32270 ulp error observe, what value `x`?

Comment: @njuffa Thanks.  As OP had range (0, 1], looks like you are testing outside that range. What `float` range did you use? [-INF ... INF]?

Comment: @njuffa  That is 8 terms + 6 terms (0.0707963258f,  ...  3.95889818E15f) for a total of 14 terms.  Sounds like a lot for a 4 ulp `float` solution for `arctan()`.  I was thinking more like 5 total terms would do it.

Comment: @aenigma For that I see maximum error = 4.17156 ulp at |x|=`0.525158107f`. I have been trying to get under 4 ulp (that is the cutoff used by Intel MKL in LP mode, which seems like a sensible bound). My best attempt so far with maximum error of 4.04336 ulp at |x|=`0.545566022f` is the following: `6.28740645e-17f, 4.86816702e-17f, 2.24875005e-18f, 4.02180358e-19f, 4.25771798e-17f, 4.25771798e-17f, 2.50182480e-17f, 1.25756335e-17f`

Comment: @aenigma: I let my heuristic optimizer run for ten days. Most accurate solution found has a maximum error of 4.02802 ulps at |x| = `0.544157028f`. Coefficients are: 
`6.28740778e-17f`, `4.86816768e-17f`, `2.24874860e-18f`, `4.02182452e-19f`, `4.25772063e-17f`, `4.25772063e-17f`, `2.50182596e-17f`, `1.25756368e-17f`

Comment: @njuffa Thank you. I am also looking for a solution that is more accurate in terms of maximum ulp. But the program will work for a long time. If I find something, I'll share it. The coefficients I initially proposed provide a solution close to optimal in terms of RMS relative error.

Comment: it reminds me code from avr-libc:
https://github.com/avrdudes/avr-libc/blob/main/libm/fplib/atan.S
it uses 8-order polynom without division. it is interesting to estimate the difference in accuracy..

Comment: @kimstik With the same theoretical error, the fractional-rational approximation will always be inferior to the polynomial in accuracy due to the need to round off the numerator, denominator, then their quotient. However, fractional-rational approximation in some cases allows you to get higher performance. The theoretical relative error of the approximation used here (excluding rounding errors) is 3E-9, which exceeds the accuracy of the float format.

Comment: @aenigma Sounds promising! Do you believe that it make sense to take into account errors under 1E-7 for 32bit floats?

Comment: @kimstik The accuracy of the approximation used should depend on the needs of the application. But if a sufficiently unified algorithm is created, it is desirable to ensure accuracy close to the full accuracy of the data format. For float-type numbers with an absolute error of half the lowest digit of the mantissa, the average relative error is about 4E-8. Accordingly, a good approximation should provide an order of magnitude better accuracy in order to eliminate systematic component of error.

Comment: Having half of ulp float32 @1.0 = 6e-8 means that we potentially have room (about one order of magnitude) for further optimizations. probably ;)

Comment: You can slightly improve the accuracy by using a polynomial. The possibilities of fractional-rational approximation are almost completely exhausted.

Comment: @njuffa Here is a solution that provides a maximum error of about 3 ulps. Coefficients are: 5.10944634e-17f, 3.95610345e-17f, 1.82743967e-18f, 3.26830821e-19f, 3.46002967e-17f, 3.46002967e-17f, 2.03310142e-17f, 1.02195567e-17f. But it gives a slightly larger mean square relative error: 2.32272978e-8 versus 2.22521892e-8.

Comment: One more, some better, solution with 3 ulps error: 5.13003486e-17, 3.97204454e-17, 1.83480364e-18, 3.28147796e-19, 3.47397196e-17, 3.47397196e-17, 2.04129398e-17, 1.02607363e-17. The RMS relative error is 2.31578183e-8.

Comment: ~1 ULPS/year ;)

Comment: :) 3 ulps (approx.) is a limit.

Comment: @aenigma For that last set of coefficients from Jun 14 I see a maximum error of 3.49637 ulps @ |x| = 0.123658605. The percentage of results that are not correctly rounded seems a bit higher than for your earlier coefficient set. This is not necessarily a reason for concern, as tuning form smallest ulp error often has that effect.

Answer (score 1):

Inverse tangent seems to be approximated really well as a polynomial in `z=x/(x+pi/3)` space. The following coefficients produce a max error of `4.07e-9` on your interval.

```
z0 = 0.0;
z1 = 1.0471985201240248;
z2 = 1.047102380719068;
z3 = 0.6678082665364844;
z4 = -0.16312555173050677;
z5 = -0.33989938855441837;
z6 = -5.8773286456840355;
z7 = 17.33961311116544;
z8 = -49.09950369422959;
z9 = 82.10190353000648;
z10 = -60.11210171537528;
z11 = 14.183376881192657;
```

You can also get down to `1.23e-14` with higher order polynomials (19th).

Here's some C# code (references Accord.net) to see the tradeoff between accuracy and number of coefficients.

```
using Accord.Math;
using Accord.Statistics.Models.Regression.Linear;
using System.Management;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

foreach(var degree in new[] { 3, 5, 7, 11, 15, 19, 23, 27 })
{
    var N = 5000;
    var ols = new OrdinaryLeastSquares() { UseIntercept = false };

    var inp = new double[N][];
    var outputs = new double[N];

    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
    {
        double x = (double)i / (double)N;

        inp[i] = new double[degree];
        inp[i][0] = x / (Math.PI /3 + x);
        for (int j = 1; j < degree; ++j)
            inp[i][j] = inp[i][0] * inp[i][j - 1];

        outputs[i] = Math.Atan(x);
    }

    MultipleLinearRegression regression = ols.Learn(inp, outputs);

    var r = new List<double>();
    foreach (var w in regression.Weights)
        Console.WriteLine(w);

    var model = inp.Dot(regression.Weights);
    var diff = 0.0;

    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
        diff = Math.Max(Math.Abs(model[i] - outputs[i]), diff);

    Console.WriteLine("++++++++++++++++++++++");
    Console.WriteLine(diff);
    Console.WriteLine("++++++++++++++++++++++");
}
Console.ReadLine();
```

Answer (score 1):

I found this that i use for x [0,+inf]

[image]

for x>2 i add +0.02 to fix

Comment: What is the average relative approximation error? Have you been optimizing constants? If the approximating function is chosen successfully, then the selection of coefficients should show good results. Is there a problem using your function when x<0?

Comment: The formula was found here: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC6010512/ I use it only for [0,+inf] range but it's not very accurate

Comment: Thanks for the link! Very interesting. Apparently, this approximation is not very accurate, but for its accuracy it has a good performance, i.e. it has the right to exist. This approximation can be improved slightly if the coefficients are optimized in it and the code is written efficiently (for example, in assembler).

Comment: By the way, the approximating function is odd, so it works for any x (including x<0).

Comment: The function you have given is the minorant of the arctangent (formulas 1.4, 1.5). To get a better approximation, you can try to take some average of the majorant and minorant coefficients. For example, the following approximate formula can be obtained from formula 1.7: atan(x) = pi^2*x/(4+sqrt((pi^2-4)*sqrt(32)+(2*pi*x)^2)).

Comment: In your formula, according to formula 1.5, the first coefficient of 8 can be replaced by 4+pi*sqrt(15)/3.