# Efficient trigonometric functions in C

Tags: c, performance, runtime, trigonometry

I am implementing some algorithms and I need to use
`cos()`, `sin()` and `atan2()`. Especially in loops these functions are very slow. For `atan2()` I am using `atan()` with some modifications:

```
double atan2_custom(double y, double x) {
    if (x > 0) {
        return atan(y / x);
    } else if (x < 0 && y >= 0) {
        return atan(y / x) + M_PI;
    } else if (x < 0 && y < 0) {
        return atan(y / x) - M_PI;
    } else if (x == 0 && y > 0) {
        return M_PI / 2;
    } else if (x == 0 && y < 0) {
        return -M_PI / 2;
    } else {
        return 0; // x and y are both zero
    }
}
```

Are there any alternatives that are more efficient to these math functions? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Note that `atan(y / x)` has big drawbacks compared to `atan2(y, x)`, even under the assumption `x > 0`.

Comment: OT: Some of the conditions are redundant (first `y<0` and the two `x==0`).

Comment: Also, can you say what precision you need? If -pi/4 <= x <= pi/4, then the naive Taylor approximation `x2=x*x; x3=x2*x; x5=x3*x2; x7=x5*x2; sin_taylor(x) = x - x3/6 + x5/120 - x7/5040` is correct up to the 8th digit.

Comment: You have to define over what range of arguments you want your trig functions to work. For my problems I can guarantee a priori that -pi <= x <= pi which means I can avoid the argument range reduction step entirely. Likewise for tan I can engineer things so that my argument will always be -pi/4 <= x <= pi/4 which allows many shortcuts and can also avoid doing a divide. Atan is about the most tricky and DIY code is unlikely to cut it. System implementations are close to as fast as you can get at full numerical precision. To go faster something has to give! What platform and what CPU ?

Comment: It would help a lot to see the sort of loop that you are using in your algorithm. FFTs use recurrence relations for most of the equally stepped values in the innermost loop and only call system sincos once per loop when the argument step length changes. sincos is always faster then sin, cos as separate calls check that your compiler is using it.

Comment: If you have both `x` and `y`, you should be using `atan2`.  That will eliminate most of your checks (possibly all of them), since having both `x` and `y` makes the quadrant clear.  You should always prefer `atan2` over `atan` unless you really only have the ratio, which is less information than having the `x` and `y` values.  So basically, the answer to this question is this:  Use `atan2`.

Comment: I actually found an option for sin and cos https://gist.github.com/giangnguyen2412/bcab883b5a53b437b980d7be9745beaf

Comment: @TomKarzes I would like to use `atan2` however it is in my case slower than my alternative

Comment: @phw It makes a bunch of checks up front to determine which octant to use for the calculation.  The result should generally be more accurate than `atan`.

Comment: Library implementors generally have already put work into making the trigonometric routines faster for general purposes. There is usually little opportunity to improve on that for general purposes. There may be opportunity to improve on it for special purposes, such as when your code does not need support for NaNs, does not need support for infinities, does not need support for arguments out of a reduced range, and so on. For assistance with that, you should specify what your special purposes are.

Comment: What is the purpose of the custom `atan2` code you show? Is it solely an attempt to be faster than `atan2`, or does it produce different results from `atan2` in some cases (e.g., zero for `atan2(0, 0)` instead of a domain error)?

Comment: @phw the "options" for sin and cos you found are toys and badly coded ones at that. Any half decent one will be a Remez approximation with weird looking coefficients slightly different to the Taylor series and giving an equal ripple error over some well defined interval. Go faster stripes include Estrin formulation but these are already present in most of the maths libraries unless you are on arcane hardware or compilers. The only modern compiler I can think of where trig is seriously slow is MinGW with its default math libraries using x87 80 bits (long double).

Comment: @MartinBrown these options might seem like a toy but atleast with them my code runs correct and way faster

Comment: You still haven't answered the question of what CPU and OS you are working on and at what numerical precision. The Intel, Arm and M1/2 math trig codes are *very* hard to beat for speed and accuracy. You have to compromise range or accuracy to go any faster. It may be possible in some circumstances but the code you pointed to really is awful. It is a testament to the effectiveness of the optimising compiler that it is even remotely competitive. If you are serious about DIY trig and special functions then the book you want is Hart, Computer Approximations (1978). Dated but has not been bettered.

Comment: @phw You may find [Fast & accurate atan/arctan approximation algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42537957/2410359) insightful.

Answer (score 1):

> Are there any alternatives that are more efficient to these math
> functions? Thanks in advance.

One of the method:

> Computes the trigonometric sine function using a combination of table
> lookup and linear interpolation.
>
> ```
> Calculation of the nearest integer table index
> Compute the fractional portion (fract) of the table index.
> The final result equals (1.0f-fract)*a + fract*b;
> ```
>
> where
>
> b = Table[index];
> c = Table[index+1];

Source: CMSIS-DSP documentation

And some example implementation: https://www.keil.com/pack/doc/CMSIS/DSP/html/arm_linear_interp_example_f32_8c-example.html#a13

Answer (score 1):

> Are there any alternatives that are more efficient to these math functions?

If one is willing to forego precision, then there are readily other time efficient alternates.

If one is willing to forego correctness, then there are even more time efficient alternates.

**Get functionality right first, then precision, before trying for speed.**

So what ever alternates you choose, **first** consider testing it for 1) correctness & 2) preciseness and rate your solution.

OP has selected one of the two most challenging functions (the other `pow()`) to code as it has many corner cases and precision issue in the extremes.

---

Following is a basic test harness.

It demos, among other short-comings, a common issue:
`atan2_custom(small_negative_y_even_minus_0, large_negative_x)` should return -pi/2, not +pi/2.

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <float.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdint.h>

#ifndef M_PI
#define M_PI 3.1415926535897932384626433832795
#endif

double atan2_custom(double y, double x) {
  if (x > 0) {
    return atan(y / x);
  } else if (x < 0 && y >= 0) {
    return atan(y / x) + M_PI;
  } else if (x < 0 && y < 0) {
    return atan(y / x) - M_PI;
  } else if (x == 0 && y > 0) {
    return M_PI / 2;
  } else if (x == 0 && y < 0) {
    return -M_PI / 2;
  } else {
    return 0; // x and y are both zero
  }
  assert(0);
  return 0;
}

static_assert(sizeof(double) == sizeof(uint64_t),"Unexpected sizes");

union double_bits {
  double d;
  uint64_t u64;
};

unsigned long long test_atan2(double (*f)(double, double), double x, double y) {
  union double_bits a0 = {.d = atan2(y, x)};
  union double_bits a1 = {.d = f(y, x)};
  if (a0.u64 == a1.u64) {
    return 0;
  }
  if (a0.u64 > a1.u64) {
    return a0.u64 - a1.u64;
  }
  return a1.u64 - a0.u64;
}

int main() {
  double (*f)(double, double) = atan2_custom;
  unsigned long long emax = 0;
  size_t eother = 0;
  const unsigned long long threshold = 1;
  static const double d[] = { //
      0, DBL_TRUE_MIN, DBL_MIN, DBL_EPSILON, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 5.0, 7.0, DBL_MAX,
      INFINITY};
  size_t n = sizeof d / sizeof d[0];
  for (unsigned signx = 0; signx < 2; signx++) {
    for (size_t xi = 0; xi < n; xi++) {
      double x = d[xi];
      if (signx)
        x = -x;
      for (unsigned signy = 0; signy < 2; signy++) {
        for (size_t yi = 0; yi < n; yi++) {
          double y = d[yi];
          if (signy)
            y = -y;
          unsigned long long e = test_atan2(f, x, y);
          if (e > emax || e > threshold) {
            if (e > emax) emax = e;

            printf(
                "x:% 24.17g y:% 24.17g, a0:% 24.17g a1: % 24.17g: error:%llu\n",
                x, y, atan2(y, x), f(y, x), e);
          } else if (e > 0) {
            eother++;
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  printf("Max error:%llu\n", emax);
  printf("Small other error count:%zu\n", eother);
}
```

Output

```
x:                       0 y:                      -0, a0:                      -0 a1:                        0: error:9223372036854775808
x:                     inf y:                     inf, a0:     0.78539816339744828 a1:                     -nan: error:13839242816598561512
x:                     inf y:                    -inf, a0:    -0.78539816339744828 a1:                     -nan: error:4615870779743785704
x:                      -0 y:                       0, a0:      3.1415926535897931 a1:                        0: error:4614256656552045848
x:                      -0 y:                      -0, a0:     -3.1415926535897931 a1:                        0: error:13837628693406821656
x:-4.9406564584124654e-324 y:                      -0, a0:     -3.1415926535897931 a1:       3.1415926535897931: error:9223372036854775808
x:-2.2250738585072014e-308 y:                      -0, a0:     -3.1415926535897931 a1:       3.1415926535897931: error:9223372036854775808
x: -2.2204460492503131e-16 y:                      -0, a0:     -3.1415926535897931 a1:       3.1415926535897931: error:9223372036854775808
x:                      -1 y:                      -0, a0:     -3.1415926535897931 a1:       3.1415926535897931: error:9223372036854775808
x:                      -2 y:                      -0, a0:     -3.1415926535897931 a1:       3.1415926535897931: error:9223372036854775808
x:                      -3 y:                      -0, a0:     -3.1415926535897931 a1:       3.1415926535897931: error:9223372036854775808
x:                      -5 y:                      -0, a0:     -3.1415926535897931 a1:       3.1415926535897931: error:9223372036854775808
x:                      -7 y:                      -0, a0:     -3.1415926535897931 a1:       3.1415926535897931: error:9223372036854775808
x:-1.7976931348623157e+308 y:                      -0, a0:     -3.1415926535897931 a1:       3.1415926535897931: error:9223372036854775808
x:                    -inf y:                     inf, a0:      2.3561944901923448 a1:                     -nan: error:13832004176781827630
x:                    -inf y:                      -0, a0:     -3.1415926535897931 a1:       3.1415926535897931: error:9223372036854775808
x:                    -inf y:                    -inf, a0:     -2.3561944901923448 a1:                     -nan: error:4608632139927051822
Max error:13839242816598561512
Small other error count:68
```

---

Follows matches `atan2()` in various corner cases.

```
#include <stdbool.h>
double atan2_custom_alt1(double y, double x) {
  bool ysignbit = signbit(y);
  if (ysignbit) {
    y = -y;
  }
  bool xsignbit = signbit(x);
  if (xsignbit) {
    x = -x;
  }
  double a;
  if (x > y) {
    a = atan(y/x);
  } else if (y > x) {
    a = M_PI/2 - atan(x/y);
  } else if (x == 0) {
    // zero/zero
    a = 0.0;
  } else {
    a = M_PI/4;
  }
  if (xsignbit) {
    a = M_PI - a;
  }
  if (ysignbit) {
    a = -a;
  }
  return a;
}
```

Perhaps later I'll try coding a better alternative, yet I would first like to know more about OP's functionality and precision requirements.

Answer (score 0):

You can try a vectorized math libary like [SLEEF](https://github.com/shibatch/sleef) to make use of your processor's SIMD capabilities.